# Regular expression for -f but not -F

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to delete all hyphens immediately before a lowercase letter of a text, but I still want to keep hyphens in the remain contexts (before uppercase, numbers, space). I tried
find: `-[a-z]` (it worked)
replace? 
I want to delete the hyphen but obviously the letter should be kept.

I am using Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `-(?=[a-z])`.

Comment: Let's cleanup these comments, I have deleted mine and will delete this later.

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group `()` to capture the lowercase letter following the `-` and use it as your replace value.

On the Replace tab:

**Find what:** `-([a-z])`
**Replace with:** `\1`
**Match case:** checked
**Regular expression:** selected

Here the `\1` tells Notepad++ to replace the found pattern with the first captured group, which will be the letter following the hyphen.